# Changing end of charger

Tags: electrical, wiring, cord-and-plug

I have s 42v charger and I need to change the end. I cut the wires only to find 5 inside the plug and the end I need only has 2,
Which do I attach my 2 wires to. And what do I do with the other wires. red green white yellow an black.[image]

Comment: Check the casing and see if there is a diagram or any wiring information. Can you provide a picture of both ends you're dealing with? I'm guessing that the two larger wires, black and red are what you want and the other ones are a ground and a control circuit to protect from over charging. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The end of the plug doesn't fit so trying to put one on that does. But it's only got 2 black wires in it where as the plug and black box has 5.

Comment: Could you explain in detail why the plug did not fit?

Comment: Your plan is not going to work. Each of those wires has a purpose. You can't ignore them, nor can you short them together.

Comment: It's a different charger. For different scooter. Just need the end changing so it fits the one I need it too

Comment: Well, yes - that's the problem - it's a different charger - and it's expecting to charge a different device - a device with 5 connections. Yours only has 2. It's not going to work (as you've already discovered). Those extra wires are for the charger and the device it's charging to talk to each other. This charger is too 'smart' for what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The extra wires are likely part of a battery management system.  These wires are used to monitor the battery being charged.  But without any sort of wiring diagram, you have no idea what these extra wires are monitoring.

They could be for charge balancing between banks of cells, making sure that each bank is equally charged.  They could be for temperature monitoring, to check that the cells aren't overheating.

If you leave them unconnected, the charger may consider that to be a fault, and refuse to charge.  Nobody knows.

Answer (score 0):

The plug you cut off is probably a DIN plug, with one or two grounds, a main DC power and one or more secondary powers. I have seen them on older DVR power supplies. Check the pairs and you will find the heavy red/black pair is the main DC volts.  The remaining wires should be folded back and insulated separately.

Comment: I joined what I thought was live to live and earth to earth and just left the other ones but it didn't work

Answer (score -2):

Pull out a voltmeter and check using continuity setting on each plug end and wire and mark accordingly then bundle the groups and done

Comment: So all 5 will attach to either one of the two black wires yeah?